# How to force Visual Studio to produce real tabs in the generated file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I noticed there is no tab in the *.cs file generated by Visual Studio even though we press tab in the editor.

I want to import the *.cs file actually. But because no tab in the file, I cannot set the `tabsize` of `\lstinputlisting{}`. For more detail see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8624/how-to-make-tabsize-also-work-for-lstinputlisting).

---

**Question:**

Is it possible to force Visual Studio to make real tabs in the generated file instead of plain spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep Visual Studio from automatically replacing tabs with spaces, you need to enable the "Keep tabs" setting for the language of your choice in the Options dialog:

[image: Keep Tabs in VS Options]

Comment: @xport: Sure thing. Out of curiosity, why are you writing LaTeX in C#?

Comment: I am not writing LaTeX in C#. The correct scenario is that I am  writing a book about C# using LaTeX as the typeset engine. So I need to import or include the C# code snippet in my book.

Comment: @Code, if the code snippet does not contain the real tab, LaTeX cannot adjust the tab spacing. It is the problem.